# While runnig pdb, it shows that empty list has been returned

Tags: python, pdb

This is a part of my code, I am trying to fix the bug by running pdb. When I put actual print statement below, I can see the list elements but while running on pdb, it returns empty list and gives the error : ZeroDivisionError

```
def assign_clusters(data, k, initialization):
    dim = data.shape
    cluster = [[] for i in range(k)]
    counter = 0
    if initialization == 'round_robin':
        if len(dim) == 1:
            for i in range(0,dim[0]):
                cluster[counter].append(data[i])
                counter += 1
                if counter == k:
                    counter = 0
    means = mean_calculation(cluster)
    lis = []
    lis.append(cluster)
    lis.append(means)   
    return lis  

def mean_calculation(cluster):
    means = [0 for j in range(len(cluster))]
    for i in range(len(cluster)):
        means[i] = sum(cluster[i])/len(cluster[i])
    return means


lis = assign_clusters(out, k, initialization)
```

While trying to see the contents of lis using print(lis), I can see the list elements but not on pdb. Can you please help me out?

Comment: That does not work either

Comment: It's just refracting the code. do you know what refracting means?

Comment: Actually I dont

Comment: since this is not a general python question it would be better if you put type hint's cause the python folks who don't know data science could understand it.

Comment: it's changing your code in a more readable, understandable, efficient way

Comment: Now that I changed that to [ [] *k] it is showing list index out of range on cluster[counter].append(data[i])

Comment: sorry it's not `[[]*k]` it's `[[]]*k`

Comment: Yeah I figured out, appreciate that